# Downloading a file given a download URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

Given certain download URLs, I would like to allow a user to download the MP4 from that site into their "Downloads" folder. The links are in the form: `http://r15---sn-o097znee.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?...B057FA94E9FC` (truncated)

When entering the website the HTML looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <video controls autoplay name="media">
            <source src="http://r15---sn-o097znee.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?...B057FA94E9FC" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

So far all I have done is create a link:

```
<a href="http://r15---sn-o097znee.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?...B057FA94E9FC" download>Download</a>
```

This is able to successfully download the MP4 into the user's "Downloads" folder but unfortunately HTML5's download attribute is not supported by all browsers.

Could someone please tell me a way to download the contents of that link that is compatible with all browsers?

I have also tried downloading using Mechanize (as shown below) but don't want to store the MP4 file in the application:

```
def download
    agent = Mechanize.new
    agent.pluggable_parser.default = Mechanize::Download
    download_url = "http://r15---sn-o097znee.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?..."
    agent.get(download_url).save('download.mp4')
end
```

Comment: have you tried to use the method send_file? http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file

Comment: I tried send_file "http://r15---sn-o097znee...", :type => "audio/mp4", :disposition => 'attachment', :filename => "download.mp4" but the error message I got was:
"Sent file http://"r15---sn-o097znee... Completed 500 in 1ms"
"ActionController:MissingFile (Cannot read file http://r15---sn-o097znee...)"

I get the same error when trying to send a simple jpg file as well so I'm probably not using it correctly:
send_file "http://www.google.com/think/images/google-trends_tools_sm.jpg", :type => "image/jpeg", :disposition => 'attachment'. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Did you find any method to download the file?